# OnTriggerStay not called every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 identical GameObjects (crates - prefabs) and 2 spots where that crates need to get. When player push first crate to spot 1, `OnTriggerStay` in script attached to that crate activate and do the job all time (print in console). Problem is that when second crate get to second spot, it do job 20-30 times (print) and then stop, then I need to just touch it (move a little) and again it does job 20-30 times and stop.

Here is script attached to crates:

```
public class Block : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BlockType blockType;
    public int blockId;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<Block>() != null)
        {
            if (col.GetComponent<Block>().blockType == BlockType.Crate && gameObject.GetComponent<Block>().blockType == BlockType.Point)
                {
                float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, col.transform.position);

                Debug.Log(col.GetComponent<Block>().blockId + ": " + distance); //for testing, distance is <= 0.05 and it doesn't display

                if (distance <= 0.05)
                {
                    PlayScene.CrateOnPoint(col.GetComponent<Block>().blockId);
                    Debug.Log("On place: " + col.GetComponent<Block>().blockId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnTriggerStay is used to detect when a GameObject is still touching with another GameObject **once**. You should not use it as a way to detect if GameObjects are touching every frame because sometimes, it is only called few times.

The best way to do this is with the `Update`, `OnTriggerEnterXXX` and the `OnTriggerExitXXX` functions with a boolean variable. You set it to `true` when in the `OnTriggerEnterXXX` is called then to `false` when `OnTriggerExitXXX`  is called. You then check this boolean variable every frame in the `Update` function.

```
bool triggered = false;

private void Update()
{
    if (triggered)
    {
        //Do something!
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Debug.Log("Entered");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("SomeObject"))
    {
        triggered = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{

    Debug.Log("Exited");
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("SomeObject"))
    {
        triggered = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i cannot do action when objects come in contact. I need then to overlay 70, 80, 90% to do action and i can not achieve that with `TriggerEnter`, `TriggerExit`

Comment: `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` both have the-same parameter as `OnTriggerStay` so there would be no problem. You have to put the current code you have in the  `OnTriggerStay` function inside the `if` statement in the `Update` function in my answer. If you need to access the `Collider2D collision` from the `Update` function, save it to a global variable when `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called then access that variable in the `Update` function.

Comment: I get it. Thank you.