# Cannot get OnTriggerEnter to loop

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Storm : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private PlayerVitals playerVitals;
    [SerializeField] private bool health;
    [SerializeField] private float value;

    public float waitTime = 1f;
    float timer;

    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating ("OnTriggerEnter", 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        }
    IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "storm") {

            playerVitals.healthSlider.value -= value;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        }
    }
    IEnumerator OnTriggerExit (Collider col){
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "storm") {

            playerVitals.healthSlider.value += value;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am working on a code for a group project and am trying to get it so that when the player is inside a trigger box, it decreases the health every second and goes back up by same amount every second they are out of the box. My group consists of only designers so coding is kind of a struggle for me but I had to watch tutorials to learn some of it for this project. p.s. I have this code attached to the player so it calls the tag "storm" which is the trigger box.

Comment: OnTriggerEnter/Exit cannot be explicitly called since they are special Unity functions. Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338177/getting-hit-after-invicibility-when-standing-on-trap/47338295#47338295) for a method on how to continously do damage with a delay.

Comment: onTriggerEnter only triggers once. Alternatively you can use [`onTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html)

Comment: Thank you both very much. I used OnTriggerStay and just had to lower the decrease value to .2 so the health would be lost at a slower rate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remove `InvokeRepeating ("OnTriggerEnter", 0.0f, 1.0f);` from the Start function. The `OnTriggerEnter` function is automatically called by Unity.

The `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` functions are called once only. Note that `OnTriggerStay` is known for not working [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940543/ontriggerstay-not-called-every-frame/45940750#45940750) and you should **avoid** using it. There are countless of posts about this on this site and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45940543/3785314) is an example.

Since you made your callback functions to be `IEnumerator`, you can actually do that in `while` a loop without freezing your game and without the `Update` function *if you want to do stuff sequentially in a coroutine function*. When `OnTriggerEnter` is called, set a flag to `true` then jump into a `while` loop with that flag. When `OnTriggerExit` is called, set that flag to `false` and the `while` loop should exit itself.

```
bool triggerEntered = false;

IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "storm")
    {
        triggerEntered = true;

        //Decrease while triggerEntered is true
        while (triggerEntered)
        {
            playerVitals.healthSlider.value -= value;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            //Exit if we hit the min value?
            if (playerVitals.healthSlider.value <= 0)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "storm")
    {
        triggerEntered = false;

        //Increase while triggerEntered is false
        while (!triggerEntered)
        {
            playerVitals.healthSlider.value += value;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            //Exit if we hit the max value?
            if (playerVitals.healthSlider.value >= 100)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I had to modify the code a bit because I got an error say that OnTriggerExit does not return a value. I simply just added the same code from OnTriggerEnter and changed everything to false and negatives. They don't do anything, however the code now works which is what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: You missed the modification I made to the  original answer. Refresh the page. It also includes incrementing the value when no collision.